# ThinkPad Backlit Keyboard and TrackPoint Not Working After 17.04 Update

Tags: kernel, thinkpad, 17.04, trackpoint, keyboard-backlight

I've been solely using Ubuntu GNOME on my **Thinkpad X250** since version 15.10. TrackPoint and Backlit Keyboard ever since functioned completely fine. (I've been upgrading my Ubuntu every six months.) Until **17.04** arrived. TrackPoint and Backlit Keyboard simply **stopped working.** <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> doesn't work anymore...

Any help to **troubleshoot** this?

Answer (score 0):

**[Facepalm]** :-)

After some testing, I had to go down to the conclusion that it was a **hardware issue.** So I opened it up and one flat cable got unfastened. (See image) I just plugged it back up and it's done. :-)

[image: Unfastened flexible flat cable that apparently powers and connects TrackPoint, Keyboard Backlight, and Touchpad hardware keys.]